# Log LUT applied before bebayering vs applied to RGB

Tags: image-processing

In order to get more detail when encoding the blacks, a log LUT is going to be applied to the pixel values.  Like gamma, the logical place to do it in the image processing pipeline is after demosaicking, so the same LUT is applied to the R,G,B components.

However, it occurs to me that a very similar effect can be achieved by applying the LUT to the bayer pattern instead.  The motivation for this is to utilize fewer logic resources (in an FPGA), since only a single LUT is required.

Is there any fundamental reason to do this after demosaicking and not before?  What about applying it to the Y component after RGB->YUV color space conversion?